# Can't Call Methods in MFC ActiveX

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, activex

I create a MFC ActiveX control with some interface methods in VS2012, and these methods work well.
When I add some new methods to the ActiveX today , **i can see the new methods** in "activex control test container", but **i can't call them**(call methods and nothing happened). This also happened in IE11 when i trying to call the method with JS. The breakpoints in these new methods will never be reached.
The old methods behave normally, and i add the new methods in the same manner. I don't know how to figure it, can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.
Here is the implementation of a new method.

```
LONG CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl::Init(LPCTSTR config)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

    MessageBox(_T("Call Init"));
    return 0;
}
```

/***************************************************************************/

I just fixed the problem.

**The statement in dispatch map must appear in the same order as their dispatch IDs in the header file.**

I added some events after i added the old methods. When I add a new method, VS add the dispatch statement to the end of BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP section, which was placed after the events dispatch statements. I moved the new method's dispatch statement to the next of the last dispatch statement of old methods, everything works well.
Here is the dispatch and events id(**Init** and **StopListen** are new methods):

```
enum {
    dispidStopListen = 11L,
    dispidInit = 10L,
    dispidTsapiDisconnected = 20L,
    dispidInterceptEnded = 19L,
    dispidInsertEnded = 18L,
    dispidListenEnded = 17L,
    dispidForceReleaseFailed = 16L,
    dispidForceReleseSuccess = 15L,
    dispidInterceptFailed = 14L,
    dispidInterceptSuccess = 13L,
    dispidStopInsertFailed = 12L,
    dispidStopInsertSuccess = 11L,
    dispidInsertFailed = 10L,
    dispidInsertSuccess = 9L,
    dispidStopListenFailed = 8L,
    dispidStopListenSuccess = 7L,
    dispidListenFailed = 6L,
    dispidListenSuccess = 5L,
    dispidLogoutFailed = 4L,
    dispidLogoutSuccess = 3L,
    dispidLoginFailed = 2L,
    dispidLoginSuccess = 1L,
    dispidForceLogout = 9L,
    dispidForceBusy = 8L,
    dispidForceFree = 7L,
    dispidIntercept = 6L,
    dispidForceRelease = 5L,
    dispidInsert = 4L,
    dispidListen = 3L,
    dispidMonitorLogout = 2L,
    dispidMonitorLogon = 1L
};
```

and here is the new **BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP** section:

```
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, COleControl)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "MonitorLogon", dispidMonitorLogon, MonitorLogon, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "MonitorLogout", dispidMonitorLogout, MonitorLogout, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "Listen", dispidListen, Listen, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "Insert", dispidInsert, Insert, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ForceRelease", dispidForceRelease, ForceRelease, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "Intercept", dispidIntercept, Intercept, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ForceFree", dispidForceFree, ForceFree, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ForceBusy", dispidForceBusy, ForceBusy, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ForceLogout", dispidForceLogout, ForceLogout, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "Init", dispidInit, Init, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "StopListen", dispidStopListen, StopListen, VT_I4, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "LoginSuccess", dispidLoginSuccess, LoginSuccess, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "LoginFailed", dispidLoginFailed, LoginFailed, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "LogoutSuccess", dispidLogoutSuccess, LogoutSuccess, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "LogoutFailed", dispidLogoutFailed, LogoutFailed, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ListenSuccess", dispidListenSuccess, ListenSuccess, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ListenFailed", dispidListenFailed, ListenFailed, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "StopListenSuccess", dispidStopListenSuccess, StopListenSuccess, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "StopListenFailed", dispidStopListenFailed, StopListenFailed, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "InsertSuccess", dispidInsertSuccess, InsertSuccess, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "InsertFailed", dispidInsertFailed, InsertFailed, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "StopInsertSuccess", dispidStopInsertSuccess, StopInsertSuccess, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "StopInsertFailed", dispidStopInsertFailed, StopInsertFailed, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "InterceptSuccess", dispidInterceptSuccess, InterceptSuccess, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "InterceptFailed", dispidInterceptFailed, InterceptFailed, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ForceReleseSuccess", dispidForceReleseSuccess, ForceReleseSuccess, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ForceReleaseFailed", dispidForceReleaseFailed, ForceReleaseFailed, VT_EMPTY, VTS_BSTR)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "ListenEnded", dispidListenEnded, ListenEnded, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "InsertEnded", dispidInsertEnded, InsertEnded, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "InterceptEnded", dispidInterceptEnded, InterceptEnded, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CDCMonitorControllerClientCtrl, "TsapiDisconnected", dispidTsapiDisconnected, TsapiDisconnected, VT_EMPTY, VTS_NONE)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()
```

I changed the location of **Init** and **StopListen**.

Comment: Have you registered your new activex dll ?

Comment: Just a guess - maybe the Release version is the registered one and your new methods are added to the Debug version, which is in a different location.

Comment: @PankajM i have register and unregister the activex for several times, none of them work.

Comment: @RogerRowland i have only one debug version of this activex control. i can see the new methods when checking this control in OLEVIEW tool, but they just don't work. that's so odd

Comment: You didn't forget to make an entry in the MFC dispatch map did you? (that is, in the `BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP` section)?

Comment: @RogerRowland i didn't forget. actually i searched a old method in the whole solution, everywhere it appears, the new methods also come out.

Comment: Well, I'm just guessing - the only source code you posted is something that you say never gets called, which doesn't help see what the problem might be. If everything you've done is correct then it must work. Try changing an existing method (e.g. to show a message) to make sure you really are running the right binary.

Comment: @RogerRowland Hi Roger, I just fixed the problem, and I updated the question, thanks for your help^_^.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed the problem.

**The statement in dispatch map must appear in the same order as their dispatch IDs in the header file.**

I have update the question for the detail, Thanks for @RogerRowland